# SSRS Reporting Services Horizontal Running Total

Tags: reporting-services, cumulative-sum

I have a weekly sales report across several locations.  I need to include the week's total and the running total for each.

```
Location       | Week1   |  Week2    | Week 3     | Total
____________________________________________________________
Boston         | $45000  |   $48000  |  $54000    | $147000
------------------------------------------------------------
Boston RTotal   | $45000  |   $93000  | $147000   |
------------------------------------------------------------
New York       | $78000  |   $84000  |  $92000    |
------------------------------------------------------------
New York RTotal | $78000  |  $162000  | $254000   | $254000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that by using `RUNNINGVALUE` function and playing around with matrix grouping settings.

First create a matrix with these groups:

[image]

Now in the highlighted cell use the following expression:

```
=RunningValue(Sum(Fields!Sales.Value),Sum,"Location")
```

Note Location is a group in my matrix.

[image]

RunningValue will evaluate the `Sum(Fields!Sales.Value)` expression and sum the values in the given scope. When you preview the report it will produce the following matrix:

[image]

Hopefully this is what you require, let me know if it helps.

Comment: For some reason, I made up in my head that you could only do this vertically.  Thanks!